# Running Python using Laravel inside WSL2 Ubuntu causes "modules not found"

Tags: python, laravel, symfony, ubuntu-20.04

I have a WSL2 Ubuntu set up with everything needed to run python scripts.

I am also using a Laravel App that uses Symfony/Process to run said-python scripts.

But when I run the script using the Laravel App, it tells me a module needed for that script is not installed.

I verified that it is installed in my Ubuntu system, and even ran the script using CLI.

This is what I use for my process in my Laravel Controller

```
$process = new Process(['/bin/python3', base_path() . /resources/python/pythonscript.py']
```

and this is what I use for the CLI command

```
/bin/python3 /var/www/laravel/resources/python/pythonscript.py
```

(I can also use just python3, but I wanted to make sure that using /bin/python3 works.)

To reiterate, the CLI works perfectly fine, while the Laravel Controller gives me a

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Any Advice?

Comment: have you tried the direct php functions? e.g. 
shell_exec

Comment: No. Symfony/Process should be a better version of shell_exec in terms of using Laravel App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the group www-data did not have access to where I installed the modules. Which was in my default $user.

To fix this, I had to install the modules using sudo.

```
e.x sudo pip3 install yfinance
```

Not so sure if this is a good solution, but it's a solution that works for me.